# Using swap space on Ubuntu 22.04, python application exit automatically

Tags: python, swap, 22.04, tensorflow

Recently I upgraded my ubuntu from 21.10 to 22.04, system works well after upgraded, but something went wrong when I run the python script, it works well on exsiting system 21.10, but didn't work on new one, BTW, it would take more swap space... when application starts, serveral times later, after it takes the swap space, the application exited automatically, I don't know what happen without any warnings, so how can I find something, or could you tell how to troubleshoot any possible reason... thanks.

Comment: Troubleshooting any issue means starting with the log files contained in `/var/log`. `syslog` may be the most useful of them if you do not have application-level logging for your Python script. Given the way your question is structured, it will be impossible to offer much help without more specific details, such as the amount of swap you have configured, what the Python script does, etc.. If the logs do not give you something to start testing, feel free to [edit] your question to add more specific details regarding the issue and perhaps someone will be able to help 

Comment: You mention *swap* rather heavily...  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has `systemd-oomd` enabled which can cause memory-hog applications to be closed automatically; clues of this will be found in logs - did you look to see if this is why it was killed as that will be shown in systemd logs.

Comment: @guiverc, that helps, I disabled it, it works now, I have more disk to make swap space to use for my tensorflow application, thanks.

Comment: Write our own answer then if it solves the issue (*credit me via tag if you wish*) stating what you did. You'll gain some SE/askubuntu *rep* via upvotes, or when/if you accept it as your answer (more *rep*). It'll also benefit others who experience what you encountered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable the systemd OOM process killer in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404888/how-do-i-disable-the-systemd-oom-process-killer-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the @guiverc's advice, I tried to disable systemd-oomd, it works well for me, here is the link how to disable the service:

[How do I disable the systemd OOM process killer in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404888/how-do-i-disable-the-systemd-oom-process-killer-in-ubuntu-22-04)