# upgrading to 22.04: earlyoomd, it is upgraded, what about systemdoomd

Tags: systemd

I habitually installed earlyoomd on ubuntu systems. When upgrading to 22.04, the earlyoomd package is cheerfully updated. But now there is systemdoomd. I'm a bit surprised by the fact that the upgrade just lets this pass without comment.

Does it matter?

Comment: Why would you be, `systemd-oomd` was announced back in [Janurary](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2022-January/041819.html), and `earlyoom` was always a Ubuntu community package found in 'universe' thus wasn't included on any Ubuntu media (*may have been in community sourced flavors though I'm not aware of any usage; I didn't look*).  You installed that community package & it's your job to maintain it. The [Ubuntu release upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) just upgrades your packages.

Comment: I think apt has a mechanism for indicating that packages are in conflict, so I filed a bug to earlyoom package in case this helps alert upgrading users. While it is true that earlyoom was only in universe, it was the leading oom user space package, and Fedora 34 even made it default. It was often recommended as the solution for desktop users, and certainly more than any other approach. If it is in conflict, it will strike more than a few users I guess.

Comment: FYI:  I don't think there is a way that would be performed; as the Ubuntu release upgrader (*see prior comment for link*) would need to be involved and I can't see that happening.  Fedora doesn't use `earlyoomd` though it used too (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/EnableSystemdOomd) but being a system enabled procedure it was dealt with in Fedora upgrades. With Ubuntu however it was never enabled by default so for me anyway; being a user-managed process seems reasonable (on *release-upgrades*).

Answer (score 3):

Why would you be?

`systemd-oomd` was announced back in [January](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2022-January/041819.html), and `earlyoom` was always a Ubuntu community package found in 'universe' thus wasn't included on any Ubuntu media (*may have been in community sourced flavors though I'm not aware of any usage; I didn't look*).

You installed that *community sourced* package & it's your job to maintain it. The [Ubuntu release upgrader](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) just upgrades your packages, including the Ubuntu community repository software.

You're free to *disable* `systemd-oomd` (see [here for how](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404888/how-do-i-disable-the-systemd-oom-process-killer-in-ubuntu-22-04)) and continue using what you used in the past.