# Ubuntu 22.04 Suddenly logs out

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, crash, logout

My ubuntu 22.04 suddenly logs out while using it.
Its ubuntu with Budgie desktop (I installed this desktop after installing ubuntu 22.04) and my laptop have a NVidia geforce GTX 1650.

I have seen some other posts about been an issue with the NVidia driver, I tested 515, 510 and currently I'm using 470.

In the /var/crash has nothing registered for the last 24 hours.

Here are the last 40 lines from journalctl.

```
jul 05 13:06:59 machine pkexec[22859]: ruivalim: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/ruivalim] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]

jul 05 13:06:59 machine pkexec[22859]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)

jul 05 13:06:28 machine systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.

jul 05 13:06:26 machine systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.

jul 05 13:06:10 machine snapd[708]: storehelpers.go:722: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "bitwarden", "code", "core", "core18", "core20", "gnome-3-28-1804", "gnome-3-34-1804", "gnome-3-38>

jul 05 13:06:10 machine PackageKit[3219]: get-details transaction /353_bdccaeed from uid 1000 finished with success after 181ms

jul 05 13:06:10 machine PackageKit[3219]: search-file transaction /352_abceeade from uid 1000 finished with success after 230ms

jul 05 13:06:10 machine PackageKit[3219]: search-file transaction /351_edcdbaac from uid 1000 finished with success after 223ms

jul 05 13:06:09 machine PackageKit[3219]: search-file transaction /350_dcdaeeda from uid 1000 finished with success after 231ms

jul 05 13:06:09 machine PackageKit[3219]: search-file transaction /349_adaceadc from uid 1000 finished with success after 556ms

jul 05 13:06:09 machine PackageKit[3219]: resolve transaction /348_dbbbbebe from uid 1000 finished with success after 738ms

jul 05 13:06:08 machine snapd[708]: storehelpers.go:722: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "bitwarden", "code", "core", "core18", "core20", "gnome-3-28-1804", "gnome-3-34-1804", "gnome-3-38>

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Weather/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Maps.desktop/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.gedit.desktop/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Evince/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Documents.desktop/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Dictionary.desktop/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.clocks.desktop/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine snap-store[21121]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Builder.desktop/* to plugin cache

jul 05 13:06:06 machine PackageKit[3219]: refresh-cache transaction /347_ddadbbbc from uid 1000 finished with success after 5589ms

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: user-129.slice: Consumed 1.965s CPU time.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of UID 129.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/129.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: user-runtime-dir@129.service: Deactivated successfully.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: run-user-129.mount: Deactivated successfully.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/129...

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: user@129.service: Consumed 1.179s CPU time.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 129.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[1]: user@129.service: Deactivated successfully.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[20119]: Reached target Exit the Session.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[20119]: Finished Exit the Session.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[20119]: Reached target Shutdown.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[20119]: Removed slice User Application Slice.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[20119]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[20119]: Closed Sound System.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[20119]: Closed debconf communication socket.

jul 05 13:06:05 machine systemd[20119]: Closed PipeWire Multimedia System Socket.
```

EDIT:

Link for more logs: https://pastebin.pl/view/a17bbbc6

Comment: the logs we need would be earlier than the ones you provided.

Comment: How much earlier?

Comment: a couple of seconds before the shutdown, probably. I can't say for sure

Comment: Here, I put the last 5 minutes https://pastebin.pl/view/a17bbbc6

Comment: Just as I was getting the logs for the time I pasted earlier it happened again....

Comment: the problem is that you're running out of memory and getting things killed by systemd-oomd

Comment: how much memory and swap space do you have? can you paste output of `free -h`?

Comment: you basically have 2 options: disable systemd-oomd and increase swap.

Comment: see both answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404888/how-do-i-disable-the-systemd-oom-process-killer-in-ubuntu-22-04) for options.

Comment: Thank you.
I disabled the systemd-oomd now, I'll keep using and see if this happens again. If it does I'll try the second option. I'll update in the next few days how this is going.

Comment: But those options make sense to my problem, because I noticed this is happening when I'm doing some heavy work on my latop.

Comment: Update: After disabling systemd-oomd my system havent log out anymore, but instead it completely frooze, so now I will try the second option, making the swap bigger, let's see

Comment: yes, systemd-oomd is supposed to prevent ever running out of memory by closing things when you're getting close. If you actually need that much memory then try increasing swap or get more RAM (if possible). Or just don't open too many programs/tabs at a time.

Comment: So just a final update for this, after all the tries the issue only disappeared when I upgraded the RAM.