# Desktop crashes randomly in 22.04, anyone know how to stop it from doing this?

Tags: crash

I am having a bizarre issue with my computer. I couldn't find much about this other than it's name, the desktop crash. Basically, what happens, is I will launch for example, a decently sized minecraft modpack. I will be playing around, enjoying myself, and everything is running smoothly. Then out of nowhere, my system black screens, showing nothing but a _ in the top left corner of my screen, then after a few seconds, I am on the lock screen, and the system behaves like I just logged out when I didn't. This isn't just limited to minecraft mods however, based on the system monitor, if I have it up displaying my stats while I am putting my system under load, the crash happens when either I hit 100% CPU usage, or 100% RAM usage. If anyone knows what is going on, please let me know how I can stop getting kicked off my computer when I push it too hard. Thank you!

Comment: Have you look for clues in the `/var/crash/` folder?  ie. what app/program is actually crashing?   Have you checked in system logs (esp. systemd; ie. `journalctl`) for clues?  ie. maybe your issue is lack of RAM & `systemd-oomd` killing an app to free some RAM; you'll evidence of this in logs. ie. look for clues

Comment: sounds like `systemd-oomd` is killing your GUI. You probably need more RAM. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417350/ubuntu-22-04-suddenly-logs-out?noredirect=1#comment2465472_1417350 (comments)