# How to determine what is the reason for force closing applications?

Tags: server, java, ram, minecraft

I'm relatively new to ubuntu and I've done a lot of googling and I can't seem to figure out the issue. So hopefully someone here can help me diagnose.

I have a desktop computer running ubuntu (22.04.1 LTS) currently. I use it right now for just family game hosting, but I will slowly integrate more uses. The computer has a 1tb m.2, i7-9700kf, and 16G of DDR4 3200. No video card or output.

The only game I host on it right now is Minecraft, using a nogui it runs the server in a command prompt basically. I use SSH to do admin stuff and access the computer, and WinSCP for file transfer between my two machines. I t typically run my minecraft server in "screen" so I don't have to leave my command prompt open.

The issue: My Minecraft server is being force closed by ubuntu. I have done all the diagnosing I can in the Minecraft world, but the server isn't crashing. Something from the computer is force closing it and all Minecraft is responding with for errors is "killed." Minecraft is allocated for 9G of memory at the moment, but I've tried anywhere from 8-12 and its still having the issue. But at 9G, it hasn't happened in a while. Which leads me to think there is a memory leak.

When I start the computer up fresh and check htop, it shows "mem" usage is around 500M/15.5G. After the server had been on for 10-12 hours, I checked it this morning. I shut down the minecraft server and the idle ram usage for the system was 4.8G now and wasn't going any less. I restarted the computer, and now its back down to idle around 500M. When the computer is fresh and the 9G minecraft server running, my ram usage sits about 9-10G and htop shows minecraft using about 52% of the memory.

Is this a known issue or where do I even start with this to get it fixed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable the systemd OOM process killer in Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404888/how-do-i-disable-the-systemd-oom-process-killer-in-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: @mikewhatever, I think it does? Atleast for why its probably getting killed. But what about the slow memory increase in htop?

Comment: Well, what about it? If Minecraft has a memory leak, as you seem to conclude, there isn't much we can do about it here. On the other hand, if it runs well with 9GB allocated, perhaps there isn't one.