# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS browser tabs crashing

Tags: 22.04, xorg, google-chrome, crash, wayland

I get chrome/brave tabs crashing on my Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ITL05, 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i3-1115G4 @ 3.00GHz × 4. 8.0 GiB. Sometimes with 3 tabs open, sometimes with 10. sometimes when I open pycharm/android studio(<=understandable), sometimes when I open a Youtube video.

I didn't have this happening on the previous version of Ubuntu, and somewhere this started happening after one of the recent updates of Ubuntu.

- One of the solutions i came across was to disable wayland - I run x11, wayland is disabled. without disabling wayland i cannot share my screen on zoom anyway.
- Some solutions suggest to turn off hardware acceleration. still doesn't resolve my issue.
- Some claim it's `systemd-oomd`, [currently the command](https://askubuntu.com/a/1415122/224435) `systemctl is-enabled systemd-oomd` returns "masked" for me. the problem still persists.

#### Update

- kernels: After researching the kernel issue, i figured it is best to stick with the current stable kernel by ubuntu which is: 5.19.0-38-generic as for March2023. I installed mainline, i tried updating to 6.2, the problem still occurred.

  I am a bit confused because when i run:

  ```
  $ sudo apt upgrade linux-generic
  [sudo] password for walid: 
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree... Done
  Reading state information... Done
  linux-generic is already the newest version (5.15.0.69.67).
  ```

  and when i run: `uname -r` i get: `5.19.0-38-generic`. Currently running `5.19.0-38-generic` but `linux-generic` seem to think i still have `5.15` maybe from the previous ubuntu version of 20.04. i really don't know.
- `sudo dmesg` - all red maked rows:

  ```
  [    0.117642] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/dswload2-162)
  [    0.117656] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
  [    0.136660] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.DGPV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
  [    0.136668] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG0.PCRP._ON due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
  [    0.509216] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
  [    1.259968] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
  [    1.262171] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Failed terminating the transaction
  [    1.262280] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus is busy, can't use it!
  [    2.994544] spi-nor spi0.0: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: c2 75 17 c2 75 17
  [    4.707741] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
  [    8.584950] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)
  [    8.584998] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
  ```

My colleague has a fresh Ubuntu installation and experience the same! At first i thought it's something to do with my setup.

We both always worked on Ubuntu in the past with no issues like this.

Edit: I installed POP_OS, and this kinda stuff doesn't happen there. So, it's not a solution, just a recommendation for a different approach.

Comment: I have the same issue on 22.04 running the latest chromium release.

Comment: @Ralph it's been 25 days since i created this post. any idea how to get some attention with it?

Comment: There should be a "Start a bounty" option below this comment section, if you'd like.

Comment: @Kar19, does this only happen when running Chrome under Wayland? Do you see similar behavior when running a different (non-Chrome) browser, like Firefox?

Comment: @Kar19, also... are you seeing anything in your OS logs (run `sudo dmesg` and look for warnings/errors that might provide some clues)? You might also try running Chrome from the command line for some clues as well.

Comment: Does switching to a different kernel work? Sounds like a kernel problem to me

Comment: @Rishon_JR didn't try but had an older post about kernels and in short it's best to update with apt update/upgrade https://askubuntu.com/q/1448998/224435

Comment: @richbl updated my main post with all the rows marked in red.

Comment: @Rishon_JR I updated my main post with kernel info i gathered. please, if you have any info.. let me know.

Comment: What graphics card are you using?

Comment: As for the kernel packages somehow mixed up, check if maybe they're marked to be held, i.e. not upgraded automatically. Run `dpkg -l | grep '^h'` to identify held packages, and if it's indeed linux-image etc. you can unhold them with `apt-mark unhold <package>`.

As for the main issue with browser crashing, is it reproducible also using a different browser engine (Firefox)? Brave is using Chromium as the rendering engine, so not that much different from Chrome itself. Also are there any other random processes crashing besides the browser?

Comment: @Kar19, have you tried running Chrome from the command line to see if the application is generating any error/warning messages?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a kernel issue to me... why? well, the kernel is the heart of Linux. It helps in running applications and etc, and keeping the integrity of Linux. Here are a few methods on how to solve this problem:

### Upgrade using `apt upgrade`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

### Upgrade by upgrading the Ubuntu release

(Almost) Every Ubuntu release comes with a newer kernel. You can try the following:

```
sudo apt update
echo "Prompt=normal" > '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades'
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Or if you wish, you can wait for two months for the release of 23.04 Lunar Lobster and run these commands

If you want to return to the LTS upgrade track, just run `echo "Prompt=lts" > '/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades'` and you are done.

### Install using `apt`

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic linux-headers-5.19.0-38 linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-38-generic linux-modules-5.19.0-38-generic
update-initramfs -u
```

### Upgrade to the mainline kernel (Not recommended)

```
apt install wget
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
chmod +x ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
sudo mv ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh /usr/local/bin/
ubuntu-mainline-kernel -i
```

I hope this helps. If any issues please leave a comment and I will try my best to give a solution and update my answer :).

Edit: You can also try following any one issue from [this article](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-kernel-ubuntu) as weel if none of them work.